# 3706 syntax error in teradata expected something between ')' and the 'AS' keyword

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql, teradata-covalent

I am getting the error message "3706 syntax error in teradata expected something between ')' and the 'AS' keyword" when try to run an update query in Teradata. There are red dotted lines on ") AS PRSCRBR_LAST_NM," on the second line of the query below. I have checked if i'm missing any comma or anything but everything looks ok.

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
PRSCRBR_LAST_NM = COALESCE(M.PRESCRIBER_LAST_NAME, 'ZZZZ1') AS PRSCRBR_LAST_NM,
PRSCRBR_FST_NM = M.PRESCRIBER_FIRST_NAME,
PRSCRBR_ADDR_LN_1 = M.PRSCRBR_ADDR_LN_1,
```

Comment: You can't have `AS aliasname` within a SET clause. There would be no point in assigning a name to the expression here because it could not be referenced anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much Fred.